# How to convert BinData type 3 data to type 4 in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I realised that my MongoDB backend stores UUID data as `BinData` type 3 and I'm finding it hard to manually trace or query documents because the UUIDs encoded through my application seem to differ from what I can see in the database. I might have to consider migrating all these to type 4, but I'm not sure how.

For example the UUID `b36148dd-e185-428d-94d9-35dacabfa635` would normally encode in base64 to `s2FI3eGFQo2U2TXayr+mNQ==`. However, it is represented in my MongoDB as `jUKF4d1IYbM1pr/K2jXZlA==` with BinData type 3 (`BinData(3, "jUKF4d1IYbM1pr/K2jXZlA==")`).

I tried creating UUID from the given UUID string above:

```
> var uuid = UUID("b36148dde185428d94d935dacabfa635")
> uuid
BinData(3,"s2FI3eGFQo2U2TXayr+mNQ==")
```

So, if I understand it correctly `BinData(3, "s2FI3eGFQo2U2TXayr+mNQ==")` is not the same as `BinData(3, "jUKF4d1IYbM1pr/K2jXZlA==")`. However, based on my tests, `BinData(4, "s2FI3eGFQo2U2TXayr+mNQ==")` (note the type 4) seems to translate to the same UUID as `BinData(3, "jUKF4d1IYbM1pr/K2jXZlA==")`. If I have a `BinData` type 3 object, how do I convert to type 4 correctly? Another question is, if I have a UUID string, how to do I properly initialise a type 3 `BinData`?

Answer (score 1):

If it is not supported by the driver, https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/#mongodb-best-practices has a java example which can be easily translated to target language:

```
/**
 * Convert a UUID object to a Binary with a subtype 0x04
 */
public static Binary toStandardBinaryUUID(java.util.UUID uuid) {
    long msb = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    long lsb = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();

    byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];

    for (int i = 15; i >= 8; i--) {
        uuidBytes[i] = (byte) (lsb & 0xFFL);
        lsb >>= 8;
    }

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        uuidBytes[i] = (byte) (msb & 0xFFL);
        msb >>= 8;
    }

    return new Binary((byte) 0x04, uuidBytes);
}

/**
 * Convert a Binary with a subtype 0x04 to a UUID object
 * Please note: the subtype is not being checked.
 */
public static UUID fromStandardBinaryUUID(Binary binary) {
    long msb = 0;
    long lsb = 0;
    byte[] uuidBytes = binary.getData();

    for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
        lsb <<= 8;
        lsb |= uuidBytes[i] & 0xFFL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        msb <<= 8;
        msb |= uuidBytes[i] & 0xFFL;
    }

    return new UUID(msb, lsb);
}
```

Basically type 3 differs from type 4 by byte order.

It's internal data storage format, so it might be enough to change the way you explore your data. Robo 3T has following options:

[image: Legacy UUID Encoding]

**UPDATE**

A quick and dirty way to find documents matching a given UUID string using mongo shell:

```
var binData3 = UUID("b36148dde185428d94d935dacabfa635")
var binData4 = UUID("b36148dd-e185-428d-94d9-35dacabfa635")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, at the moment, I'm wondering if there's a quick and dirty way to do this within just the context of Mongo (shell). If I were given only a UUID string, is there a way for me to search documents matching that without having to resort to my application code?

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately it doesn't work for type 4. Mongo shell complains about the input characters being longer than 32.